# Coloring only specific pixels

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a matrix representing an image of brain with each (i,j) position having a value between 0 and 1. I am applying a color map, so that those pixels with value 1 are red and 0 are yellow, those in between get intermediary values. Now, what i want is that those pixels having values above 0.8 get color according to colormap and rest become trasparent(that is they dont get any color), so that i can overlay this image with the another image of brain and identify high activity region. How do i do this ?

i have images like this
[image: fmri image]

I want only  the bright yellow part, so that i can overlay it with other image and get something like this.
[image: overlayed image]
<sub>(source: [psychcentral.com](https://psychcentral.com/lib/img/fmri_scan.jpg))</sub>

Edit:

I followed the  method suggested by Jigg, but recently observed that the final image was rotated and inverted , any idea why ?
[image: final_image]

Comment: The rotation/inversion effect might come from the indexing conventions. For arrays, Matlab indexes (1) top to bottom and (2) left to right; for images it's (1) left to right, (2)top to bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option, create a 3-layers array replicating your grayscale brain image (`imagesc` will scale each layer similarly resulting in equal r, g, and b values -> levels of gray).

```
GrayBckgnd = repmat(brain, [1, 1, 3]);
data = …
```

Then overlay it with the activity data:

```
imagesc(GrayBcknd);
hold on;
DataImg = imagesc(data);
set(DataImg, 'AlphaData', im2double(data>0.8));
colormap jet; % or any other colormap.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by plotting a [surf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html)(-ace) and passing in alpha values as follows.

```
brain = ... % background brain image
data = ...  % the data you are trying to overlay
imshow(brain);
hold on;
surf(zeros(size(data)), data, 'AlphaData', data > 0.8);
colormap(...); % whatever colormap you like
```

Have a look at the [surface properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surface_props.html) documentation for more options you can pass to `surf`.