# Two figures in the same plot using imagesc

Tags: matlab

I am doing some plasma and beam simulations. Now I am plotting the plasma figure using imagesc command in matlab by importing a file. I want to plot the beam figure in the same plasma figure but from another file.

Can anyone help me how to overcome this problem.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Should this be tagged `matlab` rather than `c++`? What kind of plot are you trying to overlay? What is the file format - and what do you want the result to look like?

Comment: If you are talking about blending two images together, is this on any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619451/coloring-only-specific-pixels/22620704#22620704

Answer (score 0):

In general, in Matlab you can overlay different plots using

```
hold on
```

This allows you to plot one thing, then another. Example:

```
x=0:20;
y=4*sqrt(x);
[xx yy]=meshgrid(x,y);
zz = xx.^2 + yy.^2;
figure
imagesc(zz);
axis xy  % flip the axes so origin is bottom left
hold on
plot(x, y, 'w') % plot a white curve on top of the image
```

which results in

[image]

Is that at all like what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want the plot in the same figure, but one on the left side and the other on the right side?
In this case, subplot will help you:

```
subplot(1,2,1), imagesc(data1)
subplot(1,2,2), imagesc(data2)
```