# Displaying an outline over an image?

Tags: image, matlab

I have an image 'C' of 800 x 700 pixels, and some code that finds the outline and saves this as a logical. I'd like to display the image with the outline superimposed, ideally in a specified colour such as red, but I'm running into difficulty; I've tried something like

```
imshow(C)
hold on
imshow(Outline)
```

But this doesn't work. I've also tried converting the logical to a double but am still running into trouble. Any ideas how I might do this?

Comment: Is the image RGB (800x700x3) and the outline 800x700?

Comment: Hey Rapfael - it is indeed.

Comment: In the case of mixed RGB and binary, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22620704/2777181

Comment: In addition to Jiggs answer, you could also multiply the image by your mask and get black pixels in places where there isn't any data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My usual approach for that is to edit the alpha layer:

```
imshow(C);
hold on;
h = imshow(Outline);
set(h, 'AlphaData', im2double(Outline));
colormap jet; % should make the outline red
```